# string manipulation using Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, string

i am assigning `images[]` with an array that holds images file names with full path of given Directory.

```C#
string[] images = DirLoad.FileNamesArray(
                                          IO.Loaders.PathType.full, 
                                          IO.Loaders.FileExtension.jpg
                                        );
```

...now, that `images[]` stores all the file names i need, as I had to use the **full path** to get it done,

using `Directory.GetFiles()`

Next action requires it as a **local file name**.

(each is then passed as string type parameter to another method)

so my question is :

**How can i omit first part - `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` ...if it's same in every element of array ?**

this is usage example, the string is `currentDir` i need to trim from each element in `images[]`

```C#
    public class IO
    {
        public class Loaders
        {
            readonly string currentDir = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;

            public string selecedDirName { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// assign The Loaders.selectedDir First before calling
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="foldertoLoad"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public enum PathType
            {
                full, local
            }
            public enum FileExtension
            {
                jpg,png,txt,xml,htm,js,aspx,css
            }
            public string[] FileNamesArray(PathType SelectedPathMode, FileExtension selectedfileType)
            {
                string thisFolder = "";
                string thatFileType= string.Format("*.{0}",selectedfileType.ToString());
                switch (SelectedPathMode)
                {
                    case PathType.full:
                        thisFolder = Path.Combine(currentDir, selecedDirName);
                        break;
                    case PathType.local:
                        thisFolder = selecedDirName;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                string[] foundArr = Directory.GetFiles(thisFolder, thatFileType);
                return foundArr;
            }
        }

    }
```

Update , this is what i've tried

```C#
string fileName;
string[] images = DirLoad.FilesArray(IO.Loaders.PathType.full, IO.Loaders.FileExtention.jpg);
        foreach (var currImage in images)
        {
              int startingAt = DirLoad.currentDir.Length ;
              int finalPoint = currImage.Length - startingAt;
              fileName = new String(currImage.ToCharArray(startingAt, finalPoint));
              baseStyle.Add(string.Format("{0}url({1}) {2}", BackGroundCssProp, fileName, imageProps));
        }

        return baseStyle.ToArray();
```

Comment: It;s not clear for me, what you're trying to accomplish. However is it `var fileNamesOnly = Directory.GetFiles(@"path").Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));` ??

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov..
it might ... didn't have chance to check on it ...

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov can you please post an answer , i have updated usage in my question , how do you implement `Path.GetFile()` on string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still I fail to understand, what you're trying to accomplish from the beginning to the end, but..If you are having an array of full paths and you need to get only filenames from these paths, you can do the following:

Actually `files` may contain random, absolutely different paths, but according to what I have caught from the question, et it be:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"path");
```

Then you may use [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to retrieve only filename from these paths, through a simple [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) LINQ-statement:

```
var fileNamesOnly = files.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , i will try and learn better like with using `LINQ` instead of traditional methods , it's like in jQuery and javascript i guess

Comment: At very least LINQ deserves being known. Find time to learn it. It's easy (yes, it is), powerful and useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you exactly need. For your sentence:

> the string is currentDir i need to trim from each element in images[]

You can try the following using LINQ:

```
string currDir = "SomeString";
string[] images = new string[] { "SomeStringabc1.jpg", "SomeStringabc2.jpg", "SomeStringabc3.jpg", "abc.jpg" };
string[] newImages = images.Select(r => r.StartsWith(currDir) 
                                                ? r.Replace(currDir, "") : r)
                            .ToArray();
```

Or using [string.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)

```
string[] newImages = images.Select(r => r.TrimStart(currDir.ToCharArray())).ToArray();
```

Comment: @LoneXcoder, you may post the sample array you have, and the array you want after the string manipulation.

Comment: have a look here at benchmark at the end 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

, and that was on of these full path image, for exmaple .. `G:\DevI5-Raid-0\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\testddwsSettingsViaClassToList\images\222EgplantLeatheLighterPattern.jpg`

Comment: @LoneXcoder, if you are only trying to get the file name from the path then use `.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)` as per comment of Konstantin Vasilcov, for benchmarking you may use Stopwatch and time different ways

Answer (score 1):

sorry but it is not clear to me... if you want only the filename from whole path then you can simply use Split for it, split the whole path with special character and use last array element.

once you will get all the path in your "images" array you can try below code.

for example:-

```
    for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    {
     string [] cuttofilename=images[i].split('\');
     string filename=cuttofilename[cuttofilename.lentgh-1];
    }
```

Comment: i could think about almost every option, ...as i did , i have update my question with one of possible solutions, except for @konstantin LINQ approach which i am still unfamiliar with , though your answers could look very simple... is "Kiss" still is a motto or being able to validate on some exceptions like Konstantin's list has all built-in safeties checks , i was wanting to ask what would be the best approach, like you did ( `K`eep `I`t `S`imple `S`tupid) an old term i heard, or being safe and sophisticated is better ?